# Parallel task blocking UI input in WPF using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am having a (probably not so) weird issue where I'm having a Physics update (updating positions), but can't seem to move my camera anymore (or any other user input for that matter).

The main loop gets invoked when pressing a "play" button, which just starts the physics engine. However, when positional data is updated (through the engine), I want to update all models in the scene. I have read something about a Dispacher, which works to update the models and not have an error in which I try to access `SetViewport()` that is in use by a different thread.

The models get updated how they should, and the Dispatcher works nicely (or not, idk)

The problem is that I can not seem to register user input anymore.

The weird part is, that in debug mode (I'm using Visual Studio) it sometimes does register. I have no idea why.

- The code for handling keyboard input is handled in the MazeView.
- The code for handling the "play" command is handler in the MazeModelView (using ICommand)
  That function starts a new task that starts an infinite gameloop. (I am planning on having a pause button)
- The engine logic is handled in a "Logic" project.

Here is my code:

**MazeView.cs**

```cs
        public MazeView()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            //logic = MazeViewModel.Logic;
            Viewport.PreviewKeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(OnKeyDownHandler);
            Viewport.Focusable = true;
            Viewport.Focus();

            //subscribe to event when maze is updated.
            //Update gets called when maze is generated or changed.
            MazeViewModel.MazeUpdated += SetViewport;
            if(MazeViewModel.CurrentInstance == null)
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException("Could not find viewmodel!");
            }
            model = MazeViewModel.CurrentInstance;
        }
/*
* .... rest of code
*/

private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            Key k = e.Key;
            Vector3D cameraMoveDirection = new(0, 0, 0);
            double yaw = 0, pich = 0, roll = 0;
            double zoom = 0;
            switch (k)
            {
                case Key.Z:
                    cameraMoveDirection.Z = 1;
                    break;
                case Key.S:
                    cameraMoveDirection.Z = -1;
                    break;
                case Key.Q:
                    cameraMoveDirection.X = -1;
                    break;
                case Key.D:
                    cameraMoveDirection.X = 1;
                    break;
                case Key.Space: 
                    cameraMoveDirection.Y = 1;
                    break;
                case Key.F:
                    cameraMoveDirection.Y = -1;
                    break;
                case Key.A:
                    yaw = 1;
                    break;
                case Key.E:
                    yaw = -1;
                    break;
                case Key.W:
                    zoom = 1;
                    break;
                case Key.X:
                    zoom = -1;
                    break;

            }
            model.MoveCamera(cameraMoveDirection);
            model.RotateCamera(yaw, pich, roll);
            model.ZoomCamera(zoom);
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        private void SetViewport()
        {
            Viewport.Children.Clear();

            //lighting
            DirectionalLight light = new()
            {
                Color = Colors.White,
                Direction = new Vector3D(-1, -1, -1)
            };

            Model3DGroup lightGroup = new();
            lightGroup.Children.Add(light);

            AmbientLight ambLight = new()
            {
                Color = new Color()
                {
                    R = 88,
                    G = 88,
                    B = 88
                }
            };
            lightGroup.Children.Add(ambLight);

            Viewport.Children.Add(new ModelVisual3D() { Content = lightGroup });

            Model3DGroup modelGroup = new();
            //models
            foreach (Model3D model in MazeViewModel.Models)
            {
                modelGroup.Children.Add(model);
            }
            Viewport.Children.Add(new ModelVisual3D { Content = modelGroup });
        }
}
```

---

**MazeViewModel.cs**

```cs
/*
* .... rest of code
*/
        public void OnMazeUpdate()
        {
            SetModels();
            MazeUpdated?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
        }

        private IPhysicsEngine engine;
        private CancellationTokenSource gameLoopCancellationTokenSource;
        public void PlayGame()
        {
            if(Logic == null)
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException("Can't start game because logic is null!");
            }
            engine = Logic.GetEngine(ref _maze, ref _ball);
            gameLoopCancellationTokenSource = new();
            engine.Start();
            while(!gameLoopCancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                engine.Update();
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    OnMazeUpdate();
                });
            }

        }
```

---

**PlayCommand.cs**

```
    internal class PlayGameCommand : CommandBase
    {

        private readonly MazeViewModel model;
        public PlayGameCommand(MazeViewModel model) 
        {
            this.model = model;
            MazeViewModel.MazeUpdated += OnCanExecuteChanged;
        }

        private void OnCanExecuteChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnCanExecuteChanged();
        }

        public override void Execute(object? parameter)
        {
            Task.Run(() => model.PlayGame());
        }

        public override bool CanExecute(object? parameter)
        {
            return model.Maze != null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Two guesses.  You have a tight loop somewhere burning the ui thread. In debug mode with vs attached it probably occasionally interferes enough with that loop to let you input. Async and sprinkling some await task.delay(100) around might help there.
Alternatively but similarly. Maybe you have so much dispatcher.invoke going on that the model.move etc doesn't get a chance to kick in.

Comment: I do have quite a tight loop, as the infinite loop calls `engine.update()` and `Dispatcher.Invoke()` in succession. The idea was to let that do it's thing in the 'background' and handle user input seperatly for minimal input delay.
Your talking about async and awaits, though I have no idea how to use it in this context.

Comment: At it's simplest. Literally stick the word async in whatever method game loop is. Google it. Then you can add await task.delay(100).https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=net-7.0

Comment: Yeah I get it with delay, however that kinda beats the purpose of a fast asynchronous physics engine by imposing delay